# Trouble with numpy.real for different types of arrays in python

Tags: python, numpy

I am working on an application where I need to take the real part of some numpy arrays. In this application, arrays of complex numbers seem to appear in two kinds. At least in print, one is represented as `print(a) -> [[1.+2.j]]` while the other is represented as `print(b) -> [[(1+2j)]]`; please note the distinction with the parenthesis. If I call `a.real` or `numpy.real(a)` I get the real part as expected: `print(numpy.real(a) -> [[1.]]`. However, calling `b.real` or `numpy.real(b)` appears to have no effect and I get `print(numpy.real(b)) -> [[(1+2j)]]`.

I have tried to create an MWE, but I have been unable to do so. If I create an array and populate it with complex numbers, it is printed like the array `a` above, i.e. *without* the parenthesis. Only when I print a complex scalar number is it displayed with the parenthesis.

What is the reason for the difference in the behaviour between the arrays `a` and `b` above? Is the data type somehow different (due the difference in how it is displayed with or without parenthesis) in the two arrays?

Comment: `print([np.real(item) for item in [1+2j, np.pi, 0+1j]])` gives me `[1.0, 3.141592653589793, 0.0]`. I don't know what's the problem here

Comment: Does `a.shape == b.shape`?

Comment: My guess would be that `b` has a structured dtype, but structured dtypes don't print like this - and unstructured dtypes don't print like `a` does, either. I suspect you're retyping output from memory instead of copy-pasting from actual output. If so, show us actual output.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! Yes, a and b have the same shape (1,1) and they are both  of type "numpy.ndarray". It appears that the type of b[0][0] is "complex" while the type of a[0][0] is "numpy.complex128". I am not sure how this happens, since it seems (when I try to create an MWE) that numpy would convert "complex" to "complex128".

Comment: That means your `b` array has object dtype. `b.astype(complex)` would fix that, but the fact that you ended up with an object array in the first place suggests there may be other problems to fix in the code that created that array.

Comment: An array of object dtype with a python `complex` instance in it would print like the `b` output displayed, but an array of complex128 dtype would not print like the `a` output displayed - that would print like `[[1.+2.j]]`.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks for the suggestions! Indeed, you are right. I forgot the "." in the print of a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making an array with a complex element (and dtype), and scalar complex:

```
In [101]: a=np.array([1+2j]); b=1+2j; a,b
Out[101]: (array([1.+2.j]), (1+2j))
```

`real` works for both:

```
In [102]: a.real, b.real
Out[102]: (array([1.]), 1.0)
```

but if I make an object dtype array

```
In [103]: c = np.array(b,object);c
Out[103]: array((1+2j), dtype=object)
```

now real doesn't change anything:

```
In [104]: c.real
Out[104]: array((1+2j), dtype=object)
```

This is different from making an array from `b` and allowing it to be complex dtype

```
In [106]: np.array(b), np.array(b).real
Out[106]: (array(1.+2.j), array(1.))
```